# Ping Function fails after 1020 tries

Tags: c++, sockets, ping

I have a program that needs to constantly ping a device

However this ping function fails exactlly after 1020 tries

```
int ping(string target)
{

int s, i, cc, packlen, datalen = DEFDATALEN;
struct hostent *hp;
struct sockaddr_in to, from;
//struct protoent   *proto;
struct ip *ip;
u_char *packet, outpack[MAXPACKET];
char hnamebuf[MAXHOSTNAMELEN];
string hostname;
struct icmp *icp;
int ret, fromlen, hlen;
fd_set rfds;
struct timeval tv;
int retval;
struct timeval start, end;
int /*start_t, */end_t;
bool cont = true;

to.sin_family = AF_INET;

// try to convert as dotted decimal address, else if that fails assume it's a hostname
to.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(target.c_str());
if (to.sin_addr.s_addr != (u_int)-1)
    hostname = target;
else 
{
    hp = gethostbyname(target.c_str());
    if (!hp)
    {
        cerr << "unknown host "<< target << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    to.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
    bcopy(hp->h_addr, (caddr_t)&to.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    strncpy(hnamebuf, hp->h_name, sizeof(hnamebuf) - 1);
    hostname = hnamebuf;
}
packlen = datalen + MAXIPLEN + MAXICMPLEN;
if ( (packet = (u_char *)malloc((u_int)packlen)) == NULL)
{
    cerr << "malloc error\n";
    return -1;
}

 /*
if ( (proto = getprotobyname("icmp")) == NULL)
{
    cerr << "unknown protocol icmp" << endl;
    return -1;
}
*/
if ( (s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)) < 0)
{
    perror("socket");   /* probably not running as superuser */
    return -1;
}

icp = (struct icmp *)outpack;
icp->icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;
icp->icmp_code = 0;
icp->icmp_cksum = 0;
icp->icmp_seq = 12345;  /* seq and id must be reflected */
icp->icmp_id = getpid();


cc = datalen + ICMP_MINLEN;
icp->icmp_cksum = in_cksum((unsigned short *)icp,cc);

gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

i = sendto(s, (char *)outpack, cc, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&to, (socklen_t)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if (i < 0 || i != cc)
{
    if (i < 0)
        perror("sendto error");
    cout << "wrote " << hostname << " " <<  cc << " chars, ret= " << i << endl;
}

// Watch stdin (fd 0) to see when it has input.
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(s, &rfds);
// Wait up to one seconds.
tv.tv_sec = 1;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

while(cont)
{
    retval = select(s+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (retval == -1)
    {
        perror("select()");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (retval)
    {
        fromlen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
        if ( (ret = recvfrom(s, (char *)packet, packlen, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&from, (socklen_t*)&fromlen)) < 0)
        {
            perror("recvfrom error");
            return -1;
        }

        // Check the IP header
        ip = (struct ip *)((char*)packet); 
        hlen = sizeof( struct ip ); 
        if (ret < (hlen + ICMP_MINLEN)) 
        { 
            cerr << "packet too short (" << ret  << " bytes) from " << hostname << endl;;
            return -1; 
        } 

        // Now the ICMP part 
        icp = (struct icmp *)(packet + hlen); 
        if (icp->icmp_type == ICMP_ECHOREPLY)
        {
            cout << "Recv: echo reply"<< endl;
            if (icp->icmp_seq != 12345)
            {
                cout << "received sequence # " << icp->icmp_seq << endl;
                continue;
            }
            if (icp->icmp_id != getpid())
            {
                cout << "received id " << icp->icmp_id << endl;
                continue;
            }
            cont = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Recv: not an echo reply" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        end_t = 1000000*(end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);

        if(end_t < 1)
            end_t = 1;

        cout << "Elapsed time = " << end_t << " usec" << endl;
        return end_t;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No data within one seconds.\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

If i run the ping function twice it fails at exactly half 510. And the pattern is exact. Here is the output after the 1020 mark

```
socket: Too many open files 
ping returned -1
```

Im pretty bad at network programming but i dont even know where to begin for the above code.

Am i missing a close somewhere?

The ping function is taken from: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/networking/60389-implementing-ping-c.html

*Edit*: Running Ubuntu 10.10, same issue on Fedora 13

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you simply using the `ping` utility that's already available in the operating system? It's probably better than a piece of unmaintained code that you don't understand fully.

Comment: What device could possibly need to ping constantly? I'm perfectly happy that you're bad at network programming if it keeps you from writing a ping flooder. "1020 tries ought to be enough for anybody."

Comment: @Cody Gray Being a bad network programmer usually helps you write ping flooders when you didn't intend to. It doesn't stop you from writing ones on purpose. It's bad either way. ;)

Comment: @Rosh: The hope is that you'll be mostly unsuccessful at any attempted exploits. But I see your point, and I agree.

Comment: well i dont want to ping a device constantly, i want to ping it every 15 minutes. And leave my program running, i want it to simply alert me when it goes wrong. because i want to do something after something fails i have to use C and not the system built `ping`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to close the socket with `close(s);` before exiting the function.

Comment: Hey good news is it seems to work as the ping is slowed down in comparison to before. Bad news is gota wait till 1020 to confirm your answer. Plus one none the less

Comment: Or: Divide the function into two parts. One opens the socket. The other pings the socket. Then only call open once.

Answer (score 4):

When allocating resources you need to make sure to **free** them.

As unwind pointed out, you have to **close** sockets.

But you also need to **free** the allocated memory (malloc, line 40-ish).

You should consider using [memcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcpy.html) instead of [bcopy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bcopy.html).

Comment: Yes, when malloc succeeds you need to free it afterwards. In every single (error-)case where you return.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with "unwind".

Note that you run a **function**, not a program. Hence your process is still alive, and all the memory/resource leaks are not automatically freed.

As a general rule, if you see in the code a call to a `socket` function without the corresponding `closesocket` - this must always scratch your eyes!

Comment: ahh i always thought it was the call to `connect`, and not `socket`. I was looking for the line with `connect` in it